# Need a possible proof for $A\cap B=A\cup B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to prove that-

If $A,B\subseteq U$ where $U$ is the universal set, then $A\cap B=A\cup B$.

I've been thinking a lot about it and I don;t think it's possible. Yet, I would like to confirm it for a possible proof.

What I think is that $A$ and $B$ can be mutually exclussive and thus $A\cup B$ will be something while $A\cap B$ would be a null set.

Comment: You can't prove it. It isn't true. Why would you think it was true?

Comment: As stated, the assertion is false.  Perhaps you have certain restrictions in mind for A and B?  Note that (A intersect B) = (A union B) iff A = B.

Answer (score 6):

This is not true. Take $U=\{1,2,3\}$, $A=\{1\}$ and $B=\{2\}$ for a counterexample.

Answer (score 5):

I would guess that the right question was to show that $(A \cap B)^c = A^c \cup B^c$ where $X^c$ denotes the complement of $X$ in $U$. Check your problem again.

Answer (score 3):

If $A=B$, then it is true that $A \cap B = A \cup B$.